# Compiling in JetBrains don't work

Tags: cmake, clion

I used Eclipse CDT for college lectures, but today I found the solution for C/C++ by JetBrains.

But I can't compile because I don't know how to set the compiler.

[image]

Comment: Programming and programmer's tools questions are best asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you installed cmake?  `sudo apt install cmake`

Answer (score 1):

From the error given at the bottom, it appears that while it defaulted to cmake, that the program isn't present on your computer. I would recommend running the following command in the terminal:

`sudo apt install build-essential`

This meta package contains `cmake` (which it appears is not currently installed), `g++`, `gcc`, `libc6-dev`, and `dpkg-dev`. All of which will be handy for programming on linux.

Answer (score 1):

CLion IDE for C and C++ can be installed natively by installing the clion snap package. CLion is available for a free 30-day evaluation. To install CLion in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install clion --classic
```